# SQL trigger to stop update when a condition is met

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have 3 tables: `Projects`, `Components`, and `Suppliers`.

What I am trying to do is writing a trigger that doesn't allow the value of `city` to be modified if the component and the project have the same city as the supplier.

What I have tried so far:

```
create or replace TRIGGER Supplier_control
BEFORE UPDATE of city
ON Suppliers
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_counter NUMBER := 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Suppliers s JOIN Projects p ON (s.city=p.city) JOIN Components c ON (c.city=s.city)) INTO v_counter;
    IF (v_counter != 0)
    THEN
        raise_application_error(-20111,'Can't change the city for this supplier!');
    END IF;
END;
```

After trying to run this, I am getting the following error:

```
Error at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , with group having intersect minus order start union where
   connect
```

Please note that the line number refers to the number of the line after BEGIN!

I have also tried writing the declare part before BEGIN, I am getting the following error:

```
Error at line 3: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

What needs to be done in order to get rid of these errors?

Comment: In your case, rather that creating a trigger which doesnot allow the update, you must had created a trigger which would had updated the other tow table, That would had been a robust design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some syntax errors.

1. `DECLARE` goes before the `BEGIN` statement.
2. `INTO` goes after `SELECT` and before `FROM`.
3. At `raise_application_error(-20111,'Can't change the city for this supplier!');` you cannot write `Can't` because the first single quote will end at the quote of `Can't` causing the string to end there. So you should remove it or do: `raise_application_error(-20111,'Can''t change the city for this supplier!');`

With all that being said, the full code should look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Supplier_control
BEFORE UPDATE of city
ON Suppliers
DECLARE
    v_counter NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO v_counter
    FROM (SELECT * FROM Suppliers s JOIN Projects p ON s.city=p.city JOIN Components c ON c.city=s.city);

    IF v_counter != 0 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20111,'Can''t change the city for this supplier!');
    END IF;

END;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we just prevent the update and raise no error?

Comment: @postgresnewbie The only way to prevent a row from being updated in a trigger would be to raise an exception.
You could, of course, cause the update to leave the data unchanged by simply setting the new value of each column back to the old value.

[Taken from here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2159120/trigger-in-order-to-prevent-update#:~:text=The%20only%20way%20to%20prevent,to%20the%20old%20value%2C%20i.e.)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the variable which is assigned as zero in the declaration.
set the variable from the query (result of this will be a number)

```
create or replace TRIGGER Supplier_control
BEFORE UPDATE of city
ON Suppliers
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_counter NUMBER := 0;
-- change this line
    SET v_counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Suppliers s JOIN Projects p ON (s.city=p.city) JOIN Components c ON (c.city=s.city)));
    IF (v_counter != 0)
    THEN
        raise_application_error(-20111,'Can't change the city for this supplier!');
    END IF;
END;
```

changed the count query to the edited one. First simply run the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Suppliers s JOIN Projects p ON (s.city=p.city) JOIN Components c ON (c.city=s.city))` if the output is number then assign to the variable `v_counter`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that but I still get that error that says it encountered JOIN when it was expecting something else

Comment: First simply run the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Suppliers s JOIN Projects p ON (s.city=p.city) JOIN Components c ON (c.city=s.city)) `if the output is number then assign to the variable `v_counter`

Answer (score 0):

Check ,by `lower()` or `upper()` to match including case-insensitivity, whether a city match throughout the whole table Project's values.

You don't need to and shouldn't use Supplier table in the select statement due to risk of table name is mutating error :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Supplier_control
BEFORE UPDATE of city
ON Suppliers
DECLARE 
    v_counter PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
      INTO v_counter
      FROM Projects p 
     WHERE lower(:new.city)=lower(p.city);

    IF (v_counter != 0) THEN
        raise_application_error(-20111,'Can''t change the city for this supplier!');
    END IF;
END;
```

where an initialization is redundant for `v_counter`, if there's no matching record found it would already be zero. Moreover, notice the order of `declare` keyword including variable definition part with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the overhead of a Join nor even transfer of any date. Assuming City is indexed in Projects and Components (probably should be an indexed FK), the following requires only a simple index prob on each table.

```
create or replace trigger supplier_control
before update of city
on suppliers
for each row
declare 
    project_component_exists integer ;
begin
    select null
      into project_component_exists
      from dual
     where exists ( select null 
                      from projects  
                     where city = :old.city
                  ) 
       and exists ( select null 
                      from components  
                     where city = :old.city
                  );
    raise_application_error(-20111,'Can''t change the city for this supplier!');                  
exception 
 when no_data_found
 then null;    
end;
```