# Can someone help me implement the following trigger in PL/SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

So,

I have 4 tables:

```
Suppliers( id_sup, name, city)

Products (id_prod, name, city)

Companies (id_co, name, city)

Deliveries (id_sup, id_prod, id_co)
```

I need a trigger so that if I want to update the city of a Supplier, I am not allowed if that supplier has a delivery where the product it delivers and the company it delivers to have the same city as it.

This is what I've tried so far, but it's not working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER secure_suppliers

BEFORE UPDATE ON Suppliers

BEGIN

IF UPDATING ('city') THEN

IF (suppliers.id_sup IN (SELECT id_sup FROM Deliveries) AND suppliers.city = (Select p.city From Products p INNER JOIN Deliveries d ON (p.id_prod = d.id_prod)) AND suppliers.city = (Select c.city From Companies c INNER JOIN Deliveries d ON (c.id_co = d.id_co))) THEN

RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'Can't update city!');

End if;

End;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one query to find if `product`, `supplier` and `company` are in one city with new value of the `supplier` then proceed with error handling in the `trigger` as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER secure_suppliers
    For each row -- row level trigger
    BEFORE UPDATE OF city ON Suppliers -- trigger will execute on update of column city only

DECLARE
cnt NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN    
select count(1)
Into cnt
From deliveries d
Join companies c on d.id_co = c.id_co
Join products p on d.id_prod = p.id_prod
Where p.city = c.city
And p.city = :new.city;

If cnt > 0 then
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20500, 'Can''t update city!'); 
End if;

End;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Whoaaa, it's working (well, i replaced :new.city with :old.city because it was supposed to compare it with the old value, but still, THANK YOU SO MUCH! Could you maybe explain a bit (if you have the time) what exactly was your thought process to get to this solution? How did you know to do the count/ into cnt/ cnt>0 thing and what exactly does it do?

Comment: I dont know. I really dont know. But in the trigger where I need to find the existence of something, I always works with count as it is aggregate function so if no data found then it returns 0 instead of raising exception. We can use it in IF condition then. Yes, we can take help of exceptions also in the triggers to create same logic, but pure logic should not be handled with exceptions.

Comment: If this ansaer solved your issue then please accept it so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: The same basic logic applies that applied to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125284/sql-trigger-to-stop-update-when-a-condition-is-met/59128060#59128060) regarding the same task but with only 3 of the same tables and the same requirement. Please do not ask virtually identical questions without at least explaining why the prior answers are not appropriate.